# Zope Legacy Code - Accessing DA Functions

Tags: python, zope, ingres

We're working with an older zope version (2.10.6-final, python 2.4.5) and working with a database adapter called ZEIngresDA.  We have an established connection for it, and the test function shows that it is totally functional and can connect and run queries.

My job is to change the way that the queries are actually executing, so that they're properly parameterizing variables to protect against sql injection.  With that said, I'm running into a security issue that I'm hoping someone can help with.

```
connection = container.util.ZEIngresDAName()
#returning connection at this point reveals it to be of type ZEIngresDA.db.DA,
#which is the object we're looking for.
connection.query("SELECT * from data WHERE column='%s';", ('val1',))
#query is a function that is included in class DA, functions not in DA throw errors.
```

Here we run into the problem.  Testing this script brings up a login prompt that, when logged into, immediately comes up again.  I recognize that this is likely some type of security setting, but I've been unable to find anything online about this issue, though this old of zope documentation isn't spectacular online anyways.  If this sounds familiar to you or you have any ideas, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience using Zope2 but it's hard to give a good answer with the limited information you've posted. I'm assuming here that you're using a Python script within the ZMI

Here's a list of things I would check:

- Are you logged into the root folder rather than a sub folder in the ZMI? This could cause a login prompt as you're requesting a resource that you do not have access to use
- In the ZMI double check the "security" tab of the script you're trying to run to ensure that your user role has permission to run the script
- Whilst you're there check the "proxy" tab to ensure that the script itself has permission to call the functions within it
- Also worth checking that the products you're trying to use were installed by a user which is still listed in the root acl_user folder - from memory this can cause issues with the login prompt

Best of luck to you - happy (also sad) to hear that there's at least one other Zope user out there!